# Huawei p8 lite wifi problem!

Tags: huawei

I have huawei P8 lite and there is a very funny problem here for my wifi!!!!
I am connected to my home wifi through password and my wifi shortcut key shows that I'm connected but my wifi list shows no connection! I just put the screen shots so you can understand me better..!!

[image]
[image]

Take a good look. I am connected to Huawei wifi but my wifi list shows no connection!!!
So funny, isn't it?,